# Open "Visit site" in a new window?

Tags: customization, multisite

I have managed to make the admin bar "Visit site" to open in a new window. But in a multisite setup there is a menu item called "My sites" which displays all your sites with a link to "Dashboard" and "Visit site". How do I make this "Visit site" button open in a new link?

Thank you!

EDIT: Here is the solution for the drop-down menu "My sites":

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_nodes_mysites', 999 );
function remove_nodes_mysites( $bar )
{
    $sites = get_blogs_of_user( get_current_user_id() );
    foreach ( $sites as $site )
    {
             // Open Visit Site in new window/tab
             $visit_site_node = $bar->get_node( "blog-{$site->userblog_id}-v" ); // Visit Site
             $visit_site_node->meta['target'] = '_blank';
         $bar->add_node($visit_site_node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could share exactly how you managed to do this on non-multisite setup, so others may give you answers starting from there to make it work with multisite.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Both are on the same multisite, it is just that there are two "Visit site", one in the top admin bar (which I have been able to solve), and one under the "My sites" menu. Check here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_My_Sites_Screen

Comment: I misunderstood this indeed. You could still share how you managed to solve this first part though, it can be useful as a starting point to answer your question.

Comment: Just added that to my first post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (put it in a network activated plugin):

```
add_filter( 'myblogs_blog_actions', 'my_sites_visit_site_target_blank', 10, 2 );

function my_sites_visit_site_target_blank( $actions, $user_blog ) {
    $to_replace = ">" . __( 'Visit' ) . '</a>';
    $to_replace_with = " target='_blank' >" . __( 'Visit' ) . '</a>';
    return str_replace( $to_replace, $to_replace_with, $actions );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. I think what this does is what I posted in my first post. It opens the Visit site (in the admin top bar drop down). What I am looking for is the "Visit" button/link inside the menu "My sites", check here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_My_Sites_Screen

Comment: @joq3 Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. Now I changed my answer.

Comment: Fantastic! Really appreciate it!

Comment: @joq3 Cool, no problem :)